# What is the HTML code for a double forward slash symbol //?

Tags: html, symbols, non-ascii-characters

I'm looking for a symbol that looks like two forward slashes in succession. Of course I can just enter two slashes like this: // but I would prefer a single symbol with these slashes very close together. I tried to google it, to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [COMBINING LONG DOUBLE SOLIDUS OVERLAY](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20eb/index.htm) which you can just enter directly. If you really want to use an entity then it is `&#8427;`.

```html
<p> ⃫
<p>&#8427;
```

You might find font support for it is weak though, it is an obscure combination of diacritical marks.

Comment: That's great! I would certainly prefer to enter it directly. But how do I do it?

Comment: Go to the link above and check out the links starting with 'Browser Test Page'.